# How to overlap images in R-markdown, with an option to click on the overlaid image to leave a single image behind

Tags: image, overlay, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to create a report in R Markdown (with an html output) that embeds different types of MRI images of the brain at certain levels. I want to overlay 2 images (2 different types of MRI scan) at each level of the brain, with an option to click on the top image to remove it, to see the image underneath. I'm very new to coding so am not sure how difficult my problem is, or if it is possible in R-markdown.

I am using the function knitr::include_graphics to display my images when knit to HTML, and I'm wondering what I should add to overlay 2 images, and be able click on the resultant image to either show the combined overlaid graphic, or just a solo image underneath.

Right now, I just have the 2 images one after another:

`{r echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align="center"}
library(knitr)
knitr::include_graphics('1.jpg')
knitr::include_graphics('2.jpg')`

What should I add to this chunk in R markdown, to allow for the 2 images to be overlaid; but also for the user in html to click on the resultant image, and have the overlaid option disappear and just the first image remain. Any help is appreciated, as this coding is above my level of understanding.

Thank you.